# Flutter StreamProvider does not make realtime exchanes

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I'm using streamprovider to get firestore document's realtime changing data.
(like a Streambuilder)

However when i change the data in firestroe consol while app is running, the widget does not reflect the changes.
I searched it in stackoverflow whole day and i tried several answers in here, but it doesn't go on my code.

I'm wondering what is the problem!

```dart
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  DataProvider db = DataProvider();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var userData = Provider.of<User?>(context);

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<TUser>.value(
          value: db.getUser(userData!.uid),
          initialData: TUser(email: '', uid: '', name:'', registerdate: '', recentlogindate: '', istag: false, taglist:['index']),
          updateShouldNotify: (_, __) => true,
        ),
        StreamProvider<List<Note>>.value(
          value: db.getNotes(userData.uid),
          initialData: [],
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (BuildContext context) => SideBarProvider()),
        
      ],
      child: MainPageSideBar()
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
class DataProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  
  Stream<TUser> getUser(String uid) async* {
    var snap = await _db.collection('users').doc(uid).get();

    Map<String, dynamic>? user_data = snap.data();

    yield TUser.fromMap(user_data);
  }

  Stream<List<Note>> getNotes(String uid) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('tags').snapshots()
    .map((list) =>
        list.docs.map((doc) => Note.fromMap(doc.data())).toList());
  }

}
```

```dart
//usage
    var noteDataList = Provider.of<List<Note>>(context);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several things and then I found the solution. So, I answer myself.
The problem was in DataProvider's getUser Method.
Because of async function, I guess, Stream can't reflect the changes in database.
Therefore, I changed method like this.

```dart
  Stream<TUser> getUser(String uid) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).snapshots().map((doc) => TUser.fromMap(doc.data()));
  }
```

And now, my widget changes in realtime!